# Interface method return type to be class that implements the interface

Tags: c#, interface, partial-classes

I'm having trouble getting my head around interfaces. After trawling through similar questions on here, I've come up with the following interface, for defining the CRUD operations required for all my classes:

```
public interface IData<T>
{
    IData<T> Select(int id);
    List<T> SelectMultiple();
    void Insert();
    void Update();
    void Delete();
}
```

This is then implemented within my partial classes:

```
public partial class Post : IData<Post>
{
    public IData<Post> Select(int id)
    {
        MyDataContext dc = MyDataContext.Create();
        return dc.Posts.Single(p => p.PostID == id);
    }

    public List<Post> SelectMultiple()
    {
        MyDataContext dc = MyDataContext.Create();
        return dc.Posts.ToList();
    }

    // Update() and Delete() declarations
}
```

This all compiles fine, however if I try to use the Post Select() method:

```
Post p = new Post().Select(1);
```

It fails with *Cannot implicitly convert type 'IData' to 'Post'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Which makes sense, but how do I have it so that it doesn't require a Cast? I want the Select to return a Post (but not define Post as the return type at the interface level). Have I misunderstood interfaces, or is there a quick alteration I can make?

Comment: It seems your `Post` is mixing concerns; it performs CRUD and also holds a post.  I would split it into two classes, e.g. `Post` and `PostStorage`.

Comment: The Posts are stored within SQL Server and are accessed via LinqToSQL DBML. The Post class above is a partial class of the Post within the DBML.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to return something of type `T`, not `IData<T>`, so just change the signature (at least I guess this is what you want, as you'd return `List<IData<T>>` otherwise):

```
public interface IData<T>
{
  T Select(int id);
  List<T> SelectMultiple();
  void Insert();
  void Update();
  void Delete();
}
```

and implement it appropiately:

```
public Post Select(int id)
{
    MyDataContext dc = MyDataContext.Create();
    return dc.Posts.Single(p => p.PostID == id);
}
```

If you just want this behaviour in the Post class, explicitly implement the `IData<T>` interface:

```
public partial class Post : IData<Post>
{
  public Post Select(int id)
  {
      MyDataContext dc = MyDataContext.Create();
      return dc.Posts.Single(p => p.PostID == id);
  }

  IData<Post> IData<Post>.Select(int id)
  {
      return Select(id);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the methods to return `Post` instances, then add explicit interface implementations that return the interface.

For example:

```
public partial class Post : IData<Post> {
    Post Select(int id) { ... }
    IData<Post> IData<Post>.Select(int id) { return Select(id); }
}
```

Comment: That works, but it seems odd creating one method to satisfy the Interface and another for in real-world usage.

Comment: @Lazlow, It is done more often than you may think.  It's very common when implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, for example; `IEnumerable GetEnumerator()` simply calls `IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerator()`.

Answer (score 1):

What about trying

```
public Post Select(int id)
{
    MyDataContext dc = MyDataContext.Create();
    return dc.Posts.Single(p => p.PostID == id);
}
```

i.e., return directly `Post` instead of `IData<Post>`.

Comment: Then the interface isn't implemented.

Comment: Yup, of course you 'd need to refactor that too. Actually the answer of SLaks above is the same idea, but properly developed.

Comment: That's where I started, but it wouldn't compile as the signature didn't match that of the Interface.

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly implement `IData<Post>.Select` and provide your own `Select` with the appropriate return value.  For example:

```
IData<Post> IData<Post>.Select(int id)
{
    return Select(id);
}

Post Select(int id)
{
    MyDataContext dc = MyDataContext.Create();
    return dc.Posts.Single(p => p.PostID == id);
}
```

However, if you do this:

```
IData<Post> post = new Post();
Post p = post.Select(1);
```

`post.Select(1)` still returns `IData<Post>`.  See [Femaref's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297715/interface-method-return-type-to-be-class-that-implements-the-interface/4297744#4297744) on a refactoring of the interface to allow this.