# Why can't I implement an interface method that returns an interface with a method that returns a concrete type

Tags: c#

Why can't I implement an interface method that returns an interface with a method that returns a concrete type?

E.g.:

```
public interface J
{
}

public interface I
{
   public J M();
}

public class D : J
{
}

public class C : I
{
    public D M()
    {
        return new D();
    }
}
```

gives

```
Method 'M' cannot implement method from interface '.I'. Return type should be 'J'.
```

because the compiler wants me to change the return type of `C.M` to `J`, which I don't want.

Comment: There's no `C.M` method (typo?). Also, it's easier if the code compiles (if it fails with an error it should be the error your question is about) instead of using `...` as a method body.

Comment: I had a similar problem to this fairly recently. Interfaces require you to implement the exact same type that is defined within the method, but you can create 2 definitions of the same method with different return types if you use [explicit interface implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). The interface implementation will be used when your class is being treated as an instance of the interface, and the other implementation will be used when your class is being treated as an instance of the class type.

Comment: Given Interface I... It just tells you that if you Inherit this interface, you need to create a method that is named `M` that returns The Value/Object `J`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement Interface method with subclass argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376201/how-to-implement-interface-method-with-subclass-argument) Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297715/interface-method-return-type-to-be-class-that-implements-the-interface

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes, typo, fixed. also, deleted the ellipses. It's now valid csharp syntax, but I get `Method 'M' cannot implement method from interface '.I'. Return type should be 'J'.`

Comment: @jesse thanks, i'll accept your answer if you post it

Comment: @Agent_L updated the code and the error message I get

Comment: @Peter had a typo that might have confused you. Updated my code and the error message

Comment: @Program the first link does, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230700/c-sharp-9-0-covariant-return-types-and-interfaces

Comment: Why not write `public J M() { return new D(); }`

Comment: @Klaus because that's uncertainty unnecessarily restrictive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces do not allow you to use a different return type for a defined method, even if the return type inherits from the one defined within the interface.

You can however circumvent this by using [Explicit Interface Implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). The main purpose of these implementations is if you want to create a class that inherits from multiple interfaces that have different definitions of the same method, but it can also potentially be used effectively in this situation.

However, I would be very careful when implementing this. If you don't implement it well, this has the potential to cause a lot of headache and confusion since it is effectively overriding what a class is normally forced to do when implementing an interface.

Here's an example of this:

```
public class DataClass1
{

}

public class DataClass2 : DataClass1
{

}

public interface IDataInterface
{
    public DataClass1 GetData();
}

public class DataProvider : IDataInterface
{

    public DataClass2 GetData()
    {
        return new DataClass2();
    }

    DataClass1 IDataInterface.GetData() => GetData();
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var provider = new DataProvider();
        var providerInterface = (IDataInterface)provider;

        provider.GetData(); // Returns DataClass2
        providerInterface.GetData(); // Returns DataClass1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of implementing an interface is to conform to Liskov Substitution Principle (on compile-time level). It says that every implementation of an interface is as good as any other. It gives you freedom to easily swap this implementation for another one, without having to readjust all calls.

What you're trying to do is to make this particular implementation different than others. You want a situation when your code (which knows it's dealing with this particular implementation of the interface) to instantly recognize that the returned value is of some other particular implementation.

That's way outside of the scope of your interfaces here. For out-of-interface calls use out-of interface names. Otherwise, you're breaking the very reason to have interface.

Comment: Sometimes you want to use a class as what it is, sometimes you are fine using it through an interface. The fact that there is a solution (see the comments, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) proves your theoretical arguments wrong.

Comment: @Bananach when you use explicit interface implementation then your class isn't an instance of the interface at all. It turns is-a relationship into has-a. Those aren't theoretical arguments, those are years of practice to save you from wasting time on "why it doesn't work when it should".

Comment: "theoretical" in comparison to the answer I accepted, which provides a practical solution to my problem. I may have not expressed my problem clearly enough though, so I apologize for deriding your answer as theoretical.